# Multi-view DNS PTR issues

Tags: bind, reverse-dns, ptr-record

I am seeing some problems with PTR zone resolution, and I can't quite figure out what is not configured correctly.

Summary:

1) I've been delegated authority for my PTR zone (246.237.204.in-addr.arpa, non-RFC2317), and DNS correctly shows that the SOA is my name server:

```
$ dig SOA 246.237.204.in-addr.arpa

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> SOA 246.237.204.in-addr.arpa
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 37131
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;246.237.204.in-addr.arpa.  IN  SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 2452  IN  SOA ns1.playnet.com. hostmaster.playnet.com. 2017092502 10800 900 86400 3600

;; Query time: 23 msec
;; SERVER: 17.128.100.12#53(17.128.100.12)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 27 11:30:29 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 104
```

2) My DNS is set up with multiple Views. The PTR zone is configured in in both views. I had it only in the external view at first, but when I discovered this wasn't working, I added it to the internal (LAN) view as well, just in case.

```
zone "246.237.204.in-addr.arpa" in {
    type master;
    file "db.246.237.204.rev";
    also-notify { 192.168.88.253 key external-key; };
    allow-query { any; }
};
```

3) Resolution from my LAN works as expected (dig -x 204.237.246.33 does provide the correct answer).

```
dig -x 204.237.246.33

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u13-Debian <<>> -x 204.237.246.33
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63647
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;33.246.237.204.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
33.246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN    PTR maild.playnet.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN  NS  ns1.playnet.com.
246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN  NS  ns2.playnet.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.playnet.com.    7200    IN  A   192.168.88.252
ns2.playnet.com.    7200    IN  A   192.168.88.253

;; Query time: 2 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.88.252#53(192.168.88.252)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 27 13:13:01 CDT 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 155
```

4) Resolution from OUTSIDE my LAN fails with NXDOMAIN for any configured host in the reverse zone:

```
$ dig -x 204.237.246.33

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> -x 204.237.246.33
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 13946
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;33.246.237.204.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; Query time: 95 msec
;; SERVER: 17.128.100.12#53(17.128.100.12)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 27 11:21:12 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

Q1: If the SOA is is correct, why isn't my NS being queried for this?

Now, the strange part. When I specify my nameserver in a query external to my LAN, the answer I get back from outside has a weird authority:

```
$ dig @ns1.playnet.com -x 204.237.246.33

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> @ns1.playnet.com -x 204.237.246.33
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 37679
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;33.246.237.204.in-addr.arpa.   IN  PTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA.   86400   IN  SOA 168.192.IN-ADDR.ARPA. . 0 28800 7200 604800 86400

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 204.237.246.252#53(204.237.246.252)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 27 11:14:18 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 100
```

Q2: How is it that 168.192.in-addr.arpa is showing as the authority? Where did that come from?

My internal LAN *is* an RFC 1912 network (192.168.88.0/24), and I have specified that zone in my Internal view:

```
zone "88.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
       type master;
        file "/etc/bind/internal/db.88.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
        also-notify { 192.168.88.253 key internal-key; };
};
```

Q3: Does the fact that when I query my NS directly and receive NXDOMAIN mean it's a mis-configuration on my NS, or can it be a configuration issue with my ISP?

Thanks in advance...this problem is making me lose sleep!

Answer (score 0):

Q1: I don't really understand the reasoning.

Q2: This is indeed strange, I don't believe BIND has the capability of answering with something entirely unrelated like this.

Q3: Normally, I would say "yes", but considering Q2 I suspect this may not be what is going on in this particular scenario.

I also see that one gets entirely different answers over UDP and TCP.

This combined with Q2, leads me to believe that either something else than BIND is bound to 53/udp on the WAN interface or there is something else "in the middle" that is meddling with the traffic.
Do check what process has bound to 53/udp on that address (`netstat -plnut` or similar) to begin with.

Over UDP the response is as per your question, but over TCP:

```
$ dig @204.237.246.253 -x 204.237.246.33 +norec +tcp

; <<>> DiG 9.11.1-P3-RedHat-9.11.1-2.P3.fc26 <<>> @204.237.246.253 -x 204.237.246.33 +norec +tcp
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50398
;; flags: qr aa; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 2, ADDITIONAL: 3

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;33.246.237.204.in-addr.arpa.   IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
33.246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 3600 IN    PTR     maild.playnet.com.

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN      NS      ns1.playnet.com.
246.237.204.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN      NS      ns2.playnet.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.playnet.com.        14400   IN      A       204.237.246.252
ns2.playnet.com.        14400   IN      A       204.237.246.253

;; Query time: 128 msec
;; SERVER: 204.237.246.253#53(204.237.246.253)
;; WHEN: Wed Sep 27 18:49:34 UTC 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 155

$
```